# How to move to element and press on in mob app

Tags: android, selenium, appium

How to move to element, that not visible on the screen using xpath and then click on it in mobile app?
This element located in the bottom, so need to swipe up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with:

```
TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
ta.press(button).moveTo(x, y).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example of scroll and click :

```
public void scrollDown() {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int startHeight = (int) (size.height * 0.5);
    int startWidth = (int) (size.width * 0.5);
    int endHeight = (int) (size.height * 0.25);
    int endWidth = (int) (size.width * 0.5);

    new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(startWidth, startHeight)).waitAction().moveTo(PointOption.point(endWidth, endHeight)).release().perform();
}


public void scrollUntilElementIsVisible(WebElement element) {
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        boolean flag = element.isDisplayed();
        while (!flag) {
            scrollDown();
        }
        element.click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no import for PointOption

Comment: import io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption; @qwerty

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `findElementByAndroidUIAutomator` method. It scrolls to your particular element and when it finds it, you can call `click()` on this element:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"" + Element_text + "\").instance(0))");
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Element_text\")").click();
```